# MySql max value on column fetching the entire row

Tags: mysql

Table 'teams_members'

- Team_id
- User_id

Table 'users_playeraccounts'

- User_id
- Rank_solo
- Summoner_name

Table 'users'

- Id
- Username

My target :  Fetching the current team members with their summonername and rank_solo where rank_solo is the highest out of all their playeraccounts

So multiple entries in 'users_playeraccounts' can be belong to a single user.

```
Select user_id,summoner_name,rank_solo 
    from teams_members t 
       join users_playeraccounts p on t.user_id = p.user_id  
       join users u on u.id = p.user_id 
    where team_id = 103
```

With something added I have no clue of

Comment: A team has members .Every member can have multiple summoner accounts bound to them. Every summoner account has a rank. I'm looking for a way to get every teammember with their summoner account that has the highest value out of all his accounts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select a.username, u.rank_solo, u.summoner_name 
    from teams_members as t 
    inner join users_playeraccounts as u on t.user_id = u.user_id 
    inner join users as a on a.id in (select u.user_id  from users_playeraccounts
                                           group by u.summoner_name, 
                                           having max(u.rank_solo) );
```

Comment: This still gives me every row I'm afraid. Thanks for your asnwer though!

Comment: Please explain better your goal

Comment: A team has members .Every member can have multiple summoner accounts bound to them. Every summoner account has a rank. I'm looking for a way to get every teammember with their summoner account that has the highest value out of all his accounts.

Comment: I have update the answer. I hope this could be useful;